# Spring-Boot Custom Repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have been reading about Spring Boot **custom repository**. I have dozens of blogs explaining how to implement those but none of them explained scenario when we actually need it?

I mean one example where we cannot live without custom repo. I mean if there is case of complex query, we can anyhow achieve it using `@Query`.

Please explain.

Comment: Are you talking about Spring Data JPA Repositories (nothing to do with Spring Boot) ?

Comment: yes (Spring Data JPA with Hibernate), and I am working on spring boot, that why i mentioned it

Answer (score 0):

Lets say I want strongly typed query instead of `@Query`. I would create a custom repo, autowire `EntityManager` and use [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) with it so I can use strongly typed references.

You can use it to extend the repository with other libraries that aren't part of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

I find them useful when working with a program generator like jHipster. They keep your code separate from the generated code.

The xxxRepositoryCustom.java xxxRepositoryImpl will not be overwritten when the entities are re-generated by a dumb programmer (me.)  The queries themselves have some complex logic that can not be expressed in a simple @Query